# Which Unit Test Framework is adequate for a Visual Studio 2012 TypeScript + jQuery + jQuery UI Project?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I just started a project using Typescript, jQuery and jQuery UI using Visual Studio 2012; i think it rocks. Now I am trying to write an automatic test.
   My problem is that I got overwhelmed by the choices of Unit Testing Frameworks. (QUnit, tsUnit, chutzpah... and I do not have enough experience to decide between them. I saw another entry on stack overflow but only talking about Tyspecript and leading to tsUnit. For me Typescript and jQuery are both important.
   Can anybody recommend one or a few choices for that case?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the newest version of Chutzpah, with it you can run Jasmine and Qunit Typescript tests within Visual Studio. Both Jasmine and Qunit are mature and popular and I think you should have a look at them both to see which one you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely want to use [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/). It is the most popular, was created initially to test jQuery. And is more 'classic' unit testing lib.

[Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io) is another popular testing framework, but not everyone is doing BDD.

In any case, you will need definitions for them for TypeScript, which are available at [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped).

Comment: Thanks Boris, I came back to this old post, and yes, finally Jasmine has been the best for me for now. Thinking on moving on.. but I recommend it and will still use it in other project.s